# Hacer click En Un botón con Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

Hola necesito ayuda para dar *click* a un botón usando Selenium Python 3.7, que contiene la siguiente estructura:

```
<div class="procced my-3 mx-auto">
<div class="procced" id="submitbtn">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-goo" type="submit">Click here to continue <i class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></i></button> </div>
<div id="adb_detected" class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;"></div></div>
```

Ya e intentado de todo estos son unos ejemplos:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("submitbtn").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary.btn-goo").click()
driver.find_element_by_name('Click here to continue ').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("procced.my-3.mx-auto").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("'//*[@id='submitbtn']/button'").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.btn.btn-primary.btn-goo').click()
```

Y nada que da *click* en ese botón, el botón tiene como Nombre `"Click here to continue"`, por favor necesito que alguien me ayude con este problema...

Comment: ¿Te da algún error? De ser así cargalo a la pregunta.

Comment: Hola, Gracias Por Responder Mi Pregunta, No Me Sirvió, Bueno Es Que Estoy Haciendo Un Programa Para Saltar Acortadores, Y Esta Es La URL Que Estoy Usando: https://exe.io/vyy2Y0gp   Solo Necesito Como Dar Click En El Primer Boton "Click here to continue", Por Favor Necesito Que Me Ayudes Con Esto, Y Que Me Respondas Lo Antes Posible Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Una de las formas mas fácil es  por `Xpath`, sería mas fácil si publicaras la pagina y el botón concreto, pero debería quedarte algo así:

```
boton= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit' and @class='lnr lnr-arrow-right']")[0]
boton.click()
```

fijate que para ser mas precisos llamamos a `@type='submit'` y a `@class='lnr lnr-arrow-right'`

P.D: No pude testear el funcionamiento ya que no comentas la pagina.